# Failover for pooled LDAP connections

Tags: java, spring, ldap

I am working with a Spring LDAP application for which I did none of the setup of the LDAP workings, but now I need to add a failover feature.

We supply our ContextSource with two space-seperated URLs:

```
 String theseUrls = primaryLdapUrl + " " + secondaryLdapUrl;
 environment.put("java.naming.provider.url", theseUrls);

 ilc = new InitialLdapContext(environment, null);
```

If the primary URL is functional, then it connects to that. If not, it connects to the secondary just fine. The connections are then pooled, however I am having trouble figuring out the exact mechanics. But, as it is, due to the pooling if the established connection goes down, the whole application shits the bed.

Is there a way to disable pooling, or create a short timeout for it? I have done some research but can't find exact mechanics that have worked for me (including trying to call setPooled(false)). Ideally, the secondary server is only queried if the first is down. When the first is restored, then it will go back to that.

NOTE: This URL (http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/ldap/34643-switching-ldap-contexts-for-failover) has given me a lot of ideas, but I can't get anything to work.